# Check if string could be a path (without warning)

Tags: php, validation, path, suppress-warnings

## How can I check if a string is a valid path in PHP without warning if string isn't a valid path?

When I use `file_get_contents`, `is_file`, `realpath`, `file_exists` with a string that isn't a path I get the following warning.

> "function_name()" expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in [...]

So how to determine whether the string could be a valid path or not.

---

**What the hell do you want to do? You may ask...**

Well, I want to create a function like this.

```
funtion my_smart_function( string $path_or_content )
{
    $content = is_file_without_warning_if_not_a_valid_path( $path_or_content )
             ? file_get_contents( $path_or_content )
             :                    $path_or_content;
    // do nice stuff with my $content
}
```

Sometimes `$path_or_content` will be a valid path to a file and sometimes `$path_or_content` will be the content of a file by itself (eg the binary data of an image created on the fly that doesn't even have a path (at least not yet)). In the latter case all these string related functions I mentioned above (eg `file_exists()`) will throw a warning (see quote above).

---

Something I'm wondering about.
`realpath('xyz')` doesn't throw a warning but
`realpath( file_get_contents('path/to/actual/image.jpg') )` does...

So `realpath` and the other functions mentioned above distinguish between a **string** or a **string that is a valid path**. *So how can we do either beforehand?*

Comment: [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function ?

Comment: Can you give a sample code where `file_exists` give warning as you described ?

Comment: Try `file_exists( file_get_contents('path/to/actual/image.jpg') )`. `file_get_contents` will return a string that isn't a valid pat for `file_exists`!

Comment: Why would you do this ? Why dont simply do: `file_exists('path/to/actual/image.jpg')`

Comment: @Axel It should be `if(file_exists('path/to/actual/image.jpg)) { $file = file_get_contents('path/to/actual/image.jpg'); }`

Comment: Dear friends! Please - I'm not coding for 3 days nor 3 years :)

Comment: You really have to make your use case clearer.

Comment: My function should be able to handle 2 scenarios.

#1 parameter is a path to a file: so I grab the content of that file by calling `file_get_contents`.

#2 parameter already is the content from whatever file: take the content as it is.

For both scenarios the further processing of the content is the same exact thing.

Comment: Binary content will throw this warning (specifically NUL). Do you have any other specific example ?

Comment: @Axel I placed an answer, can you please explain why that won't work?

Comment: @msg is on the right track!

Comment: Do you have an idea how to catch those cases @msg?

Comment: @Axel If that's true just add is_binary($path_or_content) or even better is_string($path_or_content)

Comment: How are you getting the parameter in such a way that you don't know whether it's a pathname or contents? Why is the application passing contents to a function that needs a filename?

Comment: Maybe start with `strpos($maybe_path, '\0') === FALSE` ?

Comment: @msg does'nt work unfortunately...

Comment: @msg it have to be `strpos($maybe_path, "\0") === FALSE` instead of `strpos($maybe_path, '\0')`. As I said you was on the right track!

Comment: The question appears to ask whether a given string could be accepted by the file system as valid, not whether the file itself is "valid" in some way, such as whether it exists. Of course, since 'abc' is a valid pathname, there is no reliable way to distinguish a string from a pathname in general. The question is really difficult to interpret.

Comment: @DavidSpector maybe this is the case because english isn't my native lang and therefore its kind of hard to explain such a techi stuff. If you have a look at the answers and the comments below eveything should become clear...

Comment: @Axel I'm glad you got your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be a reasonable time to use the `@` modifier to suppress errors.

```
funtion my_smart_function( string $path_or_content )
{
    $content =      @file_exists( $path_or_content )
             ? file_get_contents( $path_or_content )
             :                    $path_or_content;
}
```

If it's not a valid path, `file_exists()` will return a falsey value, and the `@` will keep it from complaining about the bad string.

On Linux, the only character that's not allowed in a path is the null byte. So you could just check for this:

```
if (strpos($path_or_contents, "\0") === false) {
    return file_get_contents($path_or_contents);
} else {
    return $path_or_contents;
}
```

Comment: Thats it! Thank you very much I tried with `try{}catch($e){}` before but this didn't catch the warning of cource... Thx again!

Comment: @Axel If you are on PHP 7, I believe that warnings are catchable now, using `catch (Throwable $t)`

Comment: Yes @MadhurBhaiya I'm on PHP7 but I want to keep my function backwards compatible.

Comment: @Barmar edited your answer to match the question accurately. Hope you are fine with it.

Comment: With strict types on, this still raises a `\TypeError`, which is thankfully catchable.

Comment: "f it's not a valid path, file_exists() will return false" - This is not true. If it's not a valid path, `file_exists` will return `null` (undocumented behavior *sic...). See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76406

Comment: @TheGodfather Changed to the more general "falsey value". For the purposes of the ternary, the distinction is moot.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is exactly what you want. `ctype_print` checks if all of the characters in the provided string, are printable. If so pass it to `file_exists`.

```
function my_smart_function( $path_or_content )
{

    $content = ctype_print($path_or_content) && file_exists( $path_or_content )
             ? file_get_contents( $path_or_content )
             :                    $path_or_content;

    // do nice stuff with my $content
}
```

Comment: Dear Dann thank you very much for taking some time. Your answer is exactly what I already tried. Please call `my_smart_function( file_get_contents('path/to/actual/image.jpg') )` and you will get a warning!

Comment: Of cource you have to make sure that `path/to/actual/image.jpg` actually points to an image...

Comment: @Axel I've updated my answer, can you try this example?

Comment: I've just booted up a server and tried this function. Works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Daan How did you create the invalid path in such a way that it's not a string?

Comment: Shure you have enabled `E-ALL` and working with binary data taken from an image?

Comment: @Barmar What/which invalid path? I'm really trying to understand what's going wrong here.

Comment: @Axel Of course I turned on error reporting. file_get_contents returns a string even if you're opening an image. Which binary data are you talking about now?

Comment: @Daan Sometimes the variable `$path_or_contents` contains binary data (apparently the caller already got the image data, and it's passing this as the filename) rather than a pathname.

Comment: Try something like `$path_or_content = "abc\0def";

Comment: @Barmar I see, I think we can use `ctype_print()` in this case. I will update by answer.

Comment: `ctype_print` also works like a charme but Barner was a bit faster. So I will keep his answer as the accepted one.. But +1 anyway

Comment: @Axel No worries, glad you have a solution now :)

Comment: @Daan here we go - thats the right spirit. Thx for taking some time again!

Comment: This should be an accepted answer since it doesn't contain dirty workarounds (like suppressing warnings) and also covers (probably) all undocumented cases, not only `\0` character.

Comment: This does not seem to support all valid path characters. The string "Podložak" fails, and it's a valid file name. https://3v4l.org/7Eo9N

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function. From documentation:

> file_exists — Checks whether a file or directory exists

```
bool file_exists ( string $filename )
```

> Returns TRUE if the file or directory specified by filename exists;
>   FALSE otherwise.

Comment: The question now says that `file_exists()` also reports an error.

Comment: @Barmar Question is ambiguous. Title and some of the description suggests that OP wants string to be checked as a valid path or not. However, now his smart function can take a "file content" as an input as well

Comment: The question seems pretty clear to me. He means a string that won't cause all the file-related functions to complain "<function name> expects parameter 1 to be a valid path". That's different from being a path to an existing file (`file_put_contents()` doesn't require the file to exist, since it creates it).

Comment: However `file_exists` returns null if the string is not a valid path, see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76406

Comment: `file_exists` raises a warning if the string is not a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

`file_exists` does not check that path is a valid path and has undocumented behavior. In the meantime there is no function to check whether path is valid or not. Minimal check could be as suggested by Barmar: `return strpos($path, "\0") === false`

However usually you don't want unprintable characters in your filenames neither, so it would be quite fair assumption to just use `ctype_print` function before passing the path to `file_exists` (as suggested by Daan).

**A bit of background**

Even though everyone uses `file_exists` to check... that file exists, this function (and some others) does more than that.

To be precise, it returns `null` if path is not a valid path (i.e. contains `\0`). It's a PHP [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76406).

This is very confusing behavior. Even though [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) says that `file_exists`  "Returns TRUE if the file or directory specified by filename exists; FALSE otherwise.", this is not the current implementation behavior.

As per someone's from PHP community:

> No, file_exists does not test valid paths. It tests if a "file" exists. The presumption is that the path you are giving is valid, because if not then it couldn't possibly exist.

Comment: nice additional clarification, indeed. +1